# php appearing as text in browser

Tags: php, macos, mamp

PHP files I am trying to test are appearing as text in my browser. Initially they were trying to download instead of display, but I was able to fix that. I have [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (Mac OS X Apache MySQL PHP) installed and when I entered php -v into the terminal it returned

```
PHP 5.2.14 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2010 16:57:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

indicating that php is installed. I have phpmyadmin in both Sites and MAMP, and (while testing it again right now) it appears that the Sites version is opening as text and the MAMP code from htdocs is still trying to download the php. in my httpd.conf file, i have the line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

edit: my MAMP PHP preferences defaults to PHP 5.3.5 with the option of PHP 5.2.17, however the version I am running seems to be 5.2.14, could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Try wampserver, it works out the box for me.

Comment: Just in case...have you tried restarting the server as yet?

Comment: haven't actually made any changes to the docs myself but i've restarted the computer and servers several times since installing mamp (which was about a month ago)

Comment: Does this happen with all PHP files, or just some site you're working on? Does phpMyAdmin run, oe does it display as text as well?

Comment: this is the first one i'm testing, but none of the php files seem to work

Comment: @Jim: He is running Mac OS X, hence the MAMP.

Comment: @danielle: What version of OS X are running? The PHP included with a default OS X Snow Leopard installation is PHP 5.3.4 not 5.2.14.

Comment: @x-istence *she :) . i have 10.5.8

Comment: @danielle: My sincerest apologies.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding the addtype line?

Comment: @marc b i never had to add it it was already there but i have restarted mamp several times to no avail

Answer (score 1):

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml 
Should be added in the httpd.conf

You'll also wanna make sure that php is included (not commented) out in the libraries that are loaded when apache starts.

also remember to restart apache every time you make a change.

Comment: To clarify the second point: ensure that the apache configuration file is loading the php module (in Nathan Romano's example `php5_module` is commented out and not being loaded

Comment: As posted in the original, `AddType` is already in his `httpd.conf` file

Answer (score 1):

Did you also add the line for loading the PHP module to Apache?

```
LoadModule php5_module "libexec/apache2/libphp5.so"
```

Comment: @danielle at the `httpd.conf` also.

Comment: it seems i already have this line: LoadModule php5_module        modules/php5.3/libphp5.so , confused because all the tutorials i've seen for mamp don't mention anything about these extra steps so not sure what i'm doing wrong